# Writing Script to Automtically Deploy Web App in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any ways to deploy web app in google script using script. I want to make a simple set up for a project involving web app. To make it easier i want to assign a script that automatically deploy the web app so i can do the setup in just one click, is there any ways to do it ? Thank you.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/create

Comment: Hi there @VickyLim! I strongly suggest you to take the approach commented by @Cooper. Please, try it and write back sharing your findings or doubts.

Comment: Do you want something that the Apps Script IDE can't already do?  Both the legacy and new Apps Script code editor can deploy / re-deploy a Web App.  Or are you are asking for a way for other users to "install" *your*  Web App to *their* account?

Comment: @AlanWells The new editor allows you to create new deployments, but its UI doesn't seem to allow users to re-deploy a Web App (or more precisely the existing deployment associated with the Web App) to a new version (which is still required for any updates to take hold). Unless there is some option in the UI I'm missing?

Comment: Because the legacy editor can deploy a Web App with a new version number, and keep the same published link, it would be easier to do that, than custom create a deployment script.   Using the Apps Script API, it's possible to create a new script version and a new deployment that uses the new version number.  If you wanted to use the new editor, but switch back to the legacy editor to deploy, that is obviously not ideal, but using your own code to deploy will also require opening up a different Apps Script project file.  I'm just trying to determine what the expectations are.

Comment: @AlanWells yes im asking a way to other users to install my web app in to their account.

Comment: @Cooper sorry im prettty new in this google scripting, so is that an api that i should install first or i can use it right away ?

Comment: If you want to prevent users from seeing your code, then you could publish the Web App to the Workspace Marketplace.  That's time consuming, and a lot of work.  If you are willing to "open source" your code, then the user could make a copy of your file.  Or are you are in an organization (domain) and want users inside of your organization to be able to use the Web App from their account?  Depending upon the situation the possibilities and requirements will be different.

Comment: You’ll probably have to enable it in the cloud console but it’s relatively easy to use you can take JSON copies of entire source codes and insert them into other projects they will over write he entire project. But if you’re creating a new file then it doesn’t matter

Comment: @AlanWells  yes indeed i want to make an open source code that anybody can access and make a copy to my file

Comment: @Cooper so you're saying that if i want to make a copy of the file the api should be re-enable again form the cloud console ?

Comment: I just really started using this API Alan Wells knows a lot more about it than I do but as I remember you have to enable it in the cloud console but there’s no switch in the project to enable it And there are lotta differences in that area between the new editor and the old editor that I am still unsure of how they work so again I’d trust what Alan Wells says more than what I say. But it is a valuable API to know about if you write script.

Comment: One way to provide the code to the public, is to share the Apps Script file to everyone. But only share it as "View" only, not with edit access. because you don't want people to edit or run the code from your account.  From the code editor, they can make a copy, and they will be the owner of the new file in their Drive.  No matter how the code is shared, the user needs to accept the permissions to run it.  You can share the code as a library, but that requires set-up by the user also.  Do you want something like a user clicking a button in your Web App to install the code to their account?